# Copying chars[] from one variable onto another, then changing an individual character

Tags: java

I have this variable:

```
    private String[] secretWordDictionary = { "bulbasaur", "ivysaur", "venusaur"};
```

and this method is being called:

```
        public void generateSecretWord() {
    char[] secretWord = secretWordDictionary[(int) (Math.random() * 25)].toCharArray();
    disguisedWord = secretWord;
    secretWord[2] = '?';
    System.out.println(secretWord);
    System.out.println(disguisedWord);
   }
```

Now, when I run the code, I get this as an output:

```
    bu?basaur
    bu?basaur
```

So I determined that the conversion from char to string actually worked, as well as the number generator. In the method, I made another char[] disguiseWord and assigned secretWord's chars to it. Then, I replaced the third index character of secretWord to '?'. So why does the output include the '?' for both secretWord AND disguiseWord? I only changed the third index character of secretWord and NOT disguiseWord right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Arrays in Java are objects.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html) For this reason, `disguisedWord = secretWord;` does not copy `secretWord` to `disguisedWord`, but it only **copies the reference to the same object**.

Since `disguisedWord` and `secretWord` point to the same object, every change to `secretWord` also applies to `disguisedWord`.

To solve this, [clone the array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7):

```
disguisedWord = secretWord.clone();
secretWord[2] = '?';
```

This will result in the desired outcome:

```
bu?basaur
bulbasaur
```

Comment: You, my friend, are awesome. I will buy you a coffee if I ever see you :)